# Array In multithread environment . read and Write both

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, thread-safety

I have an array of length 100. I need to use it in Multi Threaded environment.There are total 10 threads accessing array. It might be possible that two threads `t1` & `t2` want to write to same index at a time.

```
Object[] data = new Object[100];
```

What is best approach to implement this.

Solution 1 : 
Only one thread can write to an array. Even `t1` and `t2` threads want to write to different indexes , one has to wait. Even we can use `arrayList` and can use Collections.synchronizedList(....).

```
  public class ThreadSafeArray(){
    private Object[] data = new Object[100];

    public synchronized Object getValueAtIndex(int index){
       return data[index]; // Removing index range check for simple explanation
    }

    public synchronized void setValueAtIndex(int index , Object value){
      data[index] = value; // Removing index range check for simple explanation

    }
  }
```

Solution 2 :
Two different threads can write simultaneously on two different indexes.

```
        public class ThreadSafeArray(){
    private Object[] data = new Object[100];
    private Object[] lock = new Object[100];

    public Object getValueAtIndex(int index){
       synchronized(lock[index]) 
       {  
          return data[index]; // Removing index range check for simple explanation
       }
    }

    public void setValueAtIndex(int index , Object value){
       synchronized(lock[index]) 
      {
           data[index] = value; // Removing index range check for simple explanation
      } 
    }
  }
```

Is there a better way to implement this requirement?

Comment: You are better off with `Vector` or `CopyOnWriteArrayList` in JAVA

Comment: Are you doing this as an exercise or else you are reinventing the wheel. Also this question is more suitable for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @NarendraPathai                       exercise

Comment: @NarendraPathai  does CopyOnWriteArrayList will be a good soultion for this comparatively to Solution 2.

Comment: CopyOnWriteArrayList should only be used when writes are very less as compared to reads. So depends on your use case.

Comment: _"It might be possible that two threads t1 & t2 want to write to same index at a time."_ - OK, and who should be the winner then? You need additional business logic.

Comment: @HenkHolterman All threads are same . anyone can win . Can you please suggest whelther solution 2 is good or not.Or This can be implemented in a better way.

Comment: Then you would only need locking for `double` etc. For `int` and all `object` types : do nothing. `a[i] = x;` is OK then.

Comment: @HenkHolterman You still need a memory barrier for int and object types even though the writing is atomic.

Comment: @MichaelKrussel - not on x86/x64.

Comment: @ManishBhunwal - _"anyone can win"_ makes this a total nonsense scenario. You won't learn anything useful here.

Comment: @HenkHolterman The way Java's memory model works without some type of memory barrier, a thread may never see the writes another thread wrote.  So with int and object types, a reader thread will never see a partial write, but they might never see any changes made.  Also with references, another thread may see a partially constructed version of the object (same problem as the double lock singleton)

Comment: Originally there was a [C#] tag here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the second solution is better if you have a lot of threads trying to write to alot of cells and then the first way will might create a bottle neck thiner the the second solution.

in the given case of 10 threads and 100 cells there is no big difference in modern computers

Answer (score 1):

First Lets discuss the need to see what are the problems we get if we share any data among multiple threads whether it be Java/C# . 
There are three problems we need to address.

```
1. **Atomicity** of read/write operation on that datastructure
2. **Visibility** changes by one thread are visible to other thread.
3. **Reordering** - compiler n processor are free to reorder these instruction 
    as long as it maintains program order for single thread execution.
```

Now for your problem what i see is .
That you have a fixed size array and you are sharing among mulitple threads and you are just setting and getting values.

First of all reference assignments are atomic 
so therefore your below method is atomic. i will not say it is thread safe . because still it lacks
visibility gaurantees.

```
public void setValueAtIndex(int index , Object value){
      data[index] = value; // Removing index range check for simple explanation
    }
```

Now for visibility guarantees we can change our approach (in case you read outnumber your writes)

first let declare your array to volatile

```
volatile Object [] data = new Object[100];
```

now your get method will do fine without synchronized keyword

```
public Object getValueAtIndex(int index){
       return data[index]; // Removing index range check for simple explanation
}
```

The above method will be thread safe
now for set Method you may need to copy the array change the value and then again reassigned it data i.e

```
public void setValueAtIndex(int index , Object value){
      Object tempdata =  copy(data); // make a copy of that array
      //change in the copied array 
       tempdata[index] = value; 
// reassign the array back to original array
 data = tempData;   
}
```

With the above approach you will increase your performance of reading the array on the cost of writing the array. **You don’t need synchronized if you have fixed length array otherwise you need lock for mutation operations**

Comment: all reads are volatile please see data is declare volatile and on any mutation  the copied array is again assigned to data i.e volatle write . which will take care of visibility problems.

Comment: when a array is declared volatile all read through it are volatile reads

Answer (score 0):

In java, depending on how you intend to use your array, can put your values in an AbstractQueue ArrayList instead. This is one helpful one [java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html)

or any of similar queues such as

- ArrayBlockingQueue
- DelayQueue
- LinkedBlockingDeque
- SynchronousQueue

Comment: We need index base access. SEquential not necessary

Comment: @ManishBhunwal the sequence is just a bonus, you can still use the queue. Combining it with an Executor service would make it more efective. Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

Answer (score 0):

I would choose solution 1:

I think it fits your needs perfectly.

I think the performance issue can be ignored.

```
synchronize
```

your access does the job. Why make it more difficult than it is.

**Hint:** I **wouldn´t** use an array. I would better use a **Collection**. There is a collection
for everyone of your need.

Comment: First solution is as good as sequential. How is that better than second one?

Comment: I think the time that the other thread has to wait can be ignored.

Comment: Any reason to ignore the time duration for which other threads are blocked ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends whether threads only write values or also reads them (for example, to increment value by one). If they read, then synchronize on region which covers all the values - both read and written.If reading from different cells, then the 1st variant. If only from the same sell, then 2nd variant. If no values are read, then you need not synchronization at all.